# scriptblockのInvokeを使うと、起動されたスクリプトに書かれているWrite-Errorの出力が印字されない

Tags: powershell

標題の通りです。
以下のコードを実行すると、

```
function execCommand {
    Write-Error "Error"
    Write-Host "Host"
}

Write-Error "before command"
$command = [scriptblock]$function:execCommand
Write-Error "after command loaded"
$command.Invoke()
Write-Error "after exec"
```

コンソール出力には以下のように出力されます。

```
Write-Error: before command
Write-Error: after command loaded
Host
Write-Error: after exec
```

`Write-Error "Error"` の出力がされていません。
これって何故なのでしょうか？
このような動作になるメカニズムと、Invokeしたscriptblock中でもWrite-Errorで出力できる方法が知りたいです。
どなたか、ご教示の程お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptBlockを実行するのは[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3)です。`Invoke-Command $command`とすれば、期待通りの出力が得られるでしょう。

```
Write-Error: before command
Write-Error: after command loaded
Write-Error: Error
Host
Write-Error: after exec
```

---

PowerShellには3種類の構文が入り混じっています。

- PowerShellコマンドレットの実行
- C#ライクな.NETコード実行
- 外部プロセスの起動

`$command.Invoke()`はC#ライクな.NETコード実行で、これをやる場合はたぶん[`InvokeWithContext`メソッド](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0)に正しい引数を与える必要がありますが、引数を用意できないもしくは大変なので、素直にPowerShellコマンドレットで実行する方が楽です。

Comment: Invoke-Commandで `Write-Error: Error` の出力を得られました！ありがとうございました！

Comment: 私がもともと使っていたのはC#ライクな.NETコード実行だったのですね。こちらでの実装は大変そうなので、おっしゃる通りPowerShellコマンドレットの実行にとどめようと思います。こちらもご教示いただきありがとうございました！